# Obj-c, how do I create function which will populate an NSDictionary and gain a value from the function?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsdictionary

I've been reading about NSArrays and NSDictionaires and I think I need the later. I'm trying to populate an object from a small database table. So I can access the string values via a record id. I have to do this several times so putting it into an object makes sense.

I have the basics...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

// WORKING START
NSMutableDictionary *dictCategories = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dictCategories setValue:@"Utility" forKey:@"3"];
[dictCategories setValue:@"Cash" forKey:@"5"];

NSString *result;
result = [dictCategories objectForKey:@"3"];

NSLog(@"Result=%@", result);
// WORKING END

   // Can't get this bit right, current error Request for member 
   // 'getCategories' in something not a structure or union
NSMutableDictionary *dictCategories2 = self.getCategories;

NSLog(@"Result2=%@", [dictCategories2 objectForKey:@"5"]);

[super viewDidLoad];
}

-(NSMutableDictionary*)getCategories {

NSMutableDictionary *dictCategories = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[dictCategories setValue:@"Utility" forKey:@"3"];
[dictCategories setValue:@"Cash" forKey:@"5"];

return dictCategories;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling the method wrong,try [self getCategories]

Answer (score 0):

You're not being clear on what isn't working, but a few things that are obviously wrong (JonLOo might be spot on though) ...

Firstly. You're using the wrong methods, or at least there's a better one -- `setValue:forKey:` should/could be `setObject:forKey:` instead. This might be one of the reasons for your issue.

Secondly. You're over-allocating and not releasing properly. `dictCategories2` in your `viewDidLoad` will vanish into the void and bring with it the allocated memory for `dictCategories` defined in the `getCategories` method. An easy standard fix for this is to change

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictCategories = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

in `getCategories` into

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictCategories = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

It will be autoreleased using the latter method by the system.

Thirdly. You want to read up on `@property`. Instead of getFoo, setBar, the Ob-C standard is to use @properties to (pre)define setters and getter methods. You can then override these to populate default data into your methods when appropriate. You also (probably) want to store the dictionary in your interface as an instance variable, rather than letting it be deallocated all the time. Example of a @property implementation that does this:

```
@interface foo {
    NSMutableDictionary *ingredients;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *ingredients;

@end

// ....

@implementation foo

@synthesize ingredients;

// ...

// the @synthesize command above will create getter and setter methods for us but 
// we can override them, which we need to do here

- (NSMutableDictionary *)ingredients
{
    if (ingredients != nil) {
        // we've already got an ingredients variable so we just return it
        return ingredients;
    }
    // we need to create ingredients
    ingredients = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [ingredients setObject:@"foo" forKey:@"bar"]
    return ingredients;
}
```

In the viewDidLoad method (or anywhere else where you think `ingredients` might not have been initialized yet), you would do e.g.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = self.ingredients;
```

Anywhere else you can opt to use just `ingredients` without `self`, but if it's nil, your method will never be called, and you will get `nil` thrown at you.

This is useful in many cases, and is necessary if we want to ever read or write the ingredients variable from outside of our class. It's outside of what you're asking about, but I brought it up because you're trying to do something similar with `self.getCategories`.

Hope that helps.